# Choose random number from an Excel range

Tags: excel, vba, random, excel-formula

In the list bellow it's an Excel Range, I need to choose two numbers equals to 100 so in return I want to get (30 & 70) or (60 & 40). Can I do that dynamically

I use Excel but if you have any suggestion of other programs it would be fine.

> A
>   30
>   60 
>   70
>   40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the code without verification of duplicated pairs

```
Sub test()
    Dim x&, lastR&, oCell1 As Range, oCell2 As Range, Key As Variant
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    x = 1
    lastR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each oCell1 In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastR)
        For Each oCell2 In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastR)
            If oCell1.Value + oCell2.Value = 100 Then
                Dic.Add x, "(" & oCell1.Value & " & " & oCell2.Value & ")"
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each Key In Dic
         Debug.Print Key, Dic(Key) 'output in immediate window all possible
    Next
    MsgBox Dic(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Dic.Count))
End Sub
```

here the result

[image]

here the code with verification of duplicated pairs

```
Sub test()
    Dim x&, S$, S2$, check%, lastR&, oCell1 As Range, oCell2 As Range, Key As Variant
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    x = 1
    lastR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each oCell1 In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastR)
        For Each oCell2 In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastR)
            check = 0
            If oCell1.Value + oCell2.Value = 100 Then
                S = "(" & oCell1.Value & " & " & oCell2.Value & ")"
                S2 = "(" & oCell2.Value & " & " & oCell1.Value & ")"
                For Each Key In Dic
                    If Dic(Key) = S Or Dic(Key) = S2 Then
                        check = 1: Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If check = 0 Then
                    Dic.Add x, S
                    Debug.Print x, Dic(x)
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox Dic(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Dic.Count))
End Sub
```

here the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With your data in **A1** thru **A4,** try this macro:

```
Sub JustKeepTrying()
    Dim N As Long, M As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Do
        N = wf.RandBetween(1, 4)
        M = wf.RandBetween(1, 4)
        If N <> M Then
            If Cells(M, 1) + Cells(N, 1) = 100 Then
                MsgBox Cells(M, 1).Address & vbTab & Cells(M, 1).Value & vbCrLf _
                     & Cells(N, 1).Address & vbTab & Cells(N, 1).Value
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have in range `A1:a11` numbers from 0 to 100 step by 10 `[0,10,20,...,90,100]` you could use this logic (here, result is highlighted with blue color)

```
Set BaseRange = Range("A1:a11")
    BaseRange.ClearFormats

'first number- rundomly find
With BaseRange.Cells(Int(Rnd() * BaseRange.Cells.Count) + 1)
    .Interior.Color = vbBlue
    FirstNo = .Value
End With

'second number find by difference- error handling required if there is no matching value for each number
BaseRange.Find(100 - FirstNo).Interior.Color = vbBlue
```